# Scaling components java

Tags: java, scale, graphics2d

When i set the scale to say (1.2,1.2), the components get scaled by 1.2 .. But I need to scale it from center.. like zooming in from center. How to achieve this. I know i've to translate it but by what amount??

Answer (score 0):

You always have to tranlate the objects be half of their size to get to their center. So if you scale an object by 1.2, you effectively scaling the offset by 1.2 as well.

So you can easily do something like (in pseudocode):

```
obj.x += obj.width * scalingfactor / 2
obj.scaleX = scalingfactor
obj.y += obj.height * scalingfactor / 2
obj.scaleY = scalingfactor
```

Comment: Do not forget that you must scale the height too.

Comment: Here the object is whole of a JPanel and i'm zooming the entire contents of it.  Its not giving the right solution if i give translate `(this.getWidth()*zoomLevel+this.getLocation.getX(),this.getHeight()*zoomLevel+this.getLocation.getY());`